# Get database record using AJAX, Knockout and JSON

Tags: ajax, json, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am fairly new to Knockout and Entity Framework and I have a problem where I cannot seem to output any JSON from an MVC 4 controller action via an AJAX call using Knockout onto an html page.

The table includes fields Email and RegsitrationNumber, these are used to validate the user.

If the user exists in the table then their country is displayed on the screen.

The profiler states a Status Code of 200 i.e OK. Can anyone help?

HTML ------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="./Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <div>
            <h2 id="title">Login</h2>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input data-bind="value: $root.Email" type="text" title="Email" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="registrationnumber">Registration Number</label>
            <input data-bind="value: $root.RegistrationNumber" type="text" title="RegistrationNumber" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button data-bind="click: $root.login">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table id="products1" data-bind="visible: User().length > 0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Users">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Country"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>


    <script src="./Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="./Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="./Scripts/functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT -----

```
function UserViewModel() {

    //Make the self as 'this' reference
    var self = this;
    //Declare observable which will be bind with UI
    self.Name = ko.observable("Robbie");
    self.Email = ko.observable("rob@test.com");
    self.Occupation = ko.observable("Designer");
    self.Country = ko.observable("UK");
    self.RegistrationNumber = ko.observable("R009");
    self.UserDate = ko.observable("06-04-2014");

    var User = {
        Name: self.Name,
        Email: self.Email,
        Occupation: self.Occupation,
        Country: self.Country,
        RegistrationNumber: self.RegistrationNumber,
        UserDate: self.UserDate
    };

    self.User = ko.observable();  //user
    self.Users = ko.observableArray(); // list of users

    //Login
    self.login = function ()
    {
        alert("login");

        if (User.Email() != "" && User.RegistrationNumber() != "") {


            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/Login',
                cache: false,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: ko.toJSON(User),
                success: function (data) {
                    self.Users.push(data);
                    $('#title').html(data.Email);
                }
            }).fail(
                function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                    console.log('fail');
                    console.log(xhr.statusText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(err);
                });

        } else {
            alert('Please enter an email and registration number');
        }

    };


}
var viewModel = new UserViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

ACTION -----

```
   public ActionResult Login(string Email, string RegistrationNumber)
        {

            var user = from s in db.Users
                              select s;

            user = user.Where(s => s.Email.ToUpper().Equals(Email.ToUpper())
                                                 && s.RegistrationNumber.ToUpper().Equals(RegistrationNumber.ToUpper())
                                                 );

            if (user == null)
            {
               return HttpNotFound(); 
            }
            return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Can you trace the request in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and post the results?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined;
Bindings value: visible: User().length > 0 
ko.utils.extend.parseBindingsString 
ko.utils.extend.getBindings 
ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved 
evaluateImmediate 
ko.dependentObservable 
applyBindingsToNodeInternal 
applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal 
applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal 
applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal 
ko.applyBindings 
(anonymous function)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your binding is incorrect...

```
<table id="products1" data-bind="visible: Users().length > 0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Users">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Country"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`User().length` should be `Users().length`.

Comment: Thanks Dean that removed that error but now I am getting - Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: Country is not defined;
Bindings value: text: Country

Comment: Can you check the network request in your browser (in Chrome/FF press F12 and there should be a network tab there) and verify that the response does have a Country property?

Comment: Ah, ignore that. It looks like your MVC method is returning a collection of things. Change your `.Where` to a `.FirstOrDefault` instead.

Comment: This doesnt work as Im still getting an undefined error -        User user = (from u in db.Users
                         where u.Email.Equals(Email) &&
                               u.RegistrationNumber.Equals(RegistrationNumber)
                         select u).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: I think its a knockout binding problem but cant see where

Comment: You need to trace your HTTP request and see what's coming back. What you're binding to probably doesn't match what's coming back on the request...

Comment: Ok. Im getting a Status Code:200 OK but no Json data.

Comment: I had to specify the data i.e  data: '{"Email":"' + User.Email() + '","RegistrationNumber":"' + User.RegistrationNumber() + '"}',

Comment: and change from GET to POST

Comment: Dean much appreciated your help!